# How to fetch query results inside a table in Azure Wiki

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way in Azure wiki to call query results from inside a table?

For example I have 4 different queries in my Azure Boards and would like to return the results of this query within a table as below

[image]

Is there a possible way to achieve this?

The query returns results in a table structure if its called outside a table. However is there a way to call the query within a table as below?

[image]